# Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial in project generated with jhipster

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, jhipster, angularjs-injector

I am trying to add angular material to a project that i have generated using jhipster. I have added the dependencies for angular-aria, angular-animate and angular-material in index.html like this:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

I created the module like this:

```
angular
    .module('clinicPortalApp', [
        'ngStorage',
        'tmh.dynamicLocale',
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'ngResource',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngAria',
        'ngCacheBuster',
        'ngFileUpload',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
        'ui.router',
        'infinite-scroll',
        'angular-loading-bar',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngMaterial'
        // jhipster-needle-angularjs-add-module JHipster will add new module here

    ])
```

And when I run the server using maven and I am trying to access the application I am receiving the following error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module clinicPortalApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
```

In the bower_components folder I have the angular material dependency. I do not know how to solve this issue. Could you please help me?

Thanks.